# Not able to catch the IllegalStateException of MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

My code looks like this:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource( "http://.../abc.mp3" );
mp.setOnPreparedListener( ... mp.start(); ... );
mp.prepareAsync();
```

Real code has checked if `mp` is prepared before it starts. Mostly it works fine. But sometimes (if weak connection) it still encounters this error:

```
MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
MediaPlayerNative: start called in state 0, mPlayer(0x7424863b40)
```

So, I decided to catch it:

```
try {
    mp.start();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    Toast.makeText(...).show();
} catch (Throwable e) {
    Toast.makeText(...).show();
}
```

But this code does not work, I cannot catch any exception, and that error still displayed in log cat.

Comment: _"and that error still displayed in log cat"_ The exception is thrown because of that error, not the other way around. So you're not going to get rid of the error log by catching the exception.

Comment: @Michael But I still can't catch that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried hard to find out what is wrong. And I found that I didn't release the media players when the activity stops. Because the media players are still located in memory so after an exact number of times I restart the activity, the new media players cannot load. And in another activity I use SoundPool, it also cannot load more streams.

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    for (int i = 0; i < mediaPlayerMap.size(); i++) {
        int key = mediaPlayerMap.keyAt(i);
        MediaPlayer mp = mediaPlayerMap.get(key);
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
E/AudioFlinger: no more track names available
E/AudioFlinger: createTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
E/AudioTrack: AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
E/SoundPool: Error creating AudioTrack
```

Refs:

[SoundPool error: no more track names available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388053/soundpool-error-no-more-track-names-available)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-platform/tyITQ09vV3s/jwNdyI2-7iYJ

Answer (score 1):

You should use `prepare` instead of `prepareAsync` if you intend to call `start` immediately afterward. You get `IllegalStateException` because it may be out-of-sync when you call `start`, as it prepares asynchronously and has not finished the transaction yet.

According to [prepareAsync](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#prepareAsync()):

> Prepares the player for playback, asynchronously. After setting the
>   datasource and the display surface, you need to either call prepare()
>   or prepareAsync(). For streams, you should call prepareAsync(), **which
>   returns immediately, rather than blocking until enough data has been
>   buffered.**

And [prepare](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#prepare()):

> Prepares the player for playback, **synchronously**. After setting the
>   datasource and the display surface, you need to either call prepare()
>   or prepareAsync(). For files, it is OK to call prepare(), which blocks
>   until MediaPlayer is ready for playback.

Again, `prepare` allows you to call `start` immediately because it runs synchronously. However, there may be other cases that can throw `IllegalStateException`, please refer to its [valid and invalid states](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#Valid_and_Invalid_States).

Comment: I've tried both `prepare` and `prepareAsync`. They worked fine in most time. But sometimes did not (rarely). And I would like to handle these case

Comment: Understood, `prepare` then `start` should work fine, but there are also other cases that can throw `IllegalStateException`, please refer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#Valid_and_Invalid_States and check your code again. :)

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to release the media players when the activity stops. And this error occurred after an exact number of times I restart the activity